# Zend - How to get individual radio button in viewscript

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, zend-framework

I'm setting the radio button like this:

```
$gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('gender');
$gender->setLabel('Gender')
    ->addMultiOptions(array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female'))
    ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'))
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, $required);
```

And I want to retrieve the inputs it creates individually in the viewscript. I've tried:

```
$fields = $this->element->getElements();
$fields['gender']->getMultiOption('m')
```

But that just gets the value 'Male'. How can I get the individual radio inputs that `addMultiOptions` generates?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using getMultiOptions()-method:

```
$fields = $this->element->getElements();
$options = $fields['gender']->getMultiOptions();
```

Here's an example how to get the radio buttons rendered:

```
$fields = $this->element->getElements();
echo "<label>{$fields['gender']->getLabel()}</label>";
foreach($fields['gender']->getMultiOptions() as $value => $label) {
    echo '<input type="radio" value="' . $value . '" name="gender" /> ' . $label;
}
```

Comment: that does the same as `getMultiOption('m')` except it gets both strings eg `array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female')`

Comment: That's the point - you need to generate the radio buttons with these information on your own if you are not using the elements render()-method. There is no way to get the html for a specific button - only for the element.

Comment: Are you saying what I want to do is not possible? If not could you provide an example of how it would work? Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do is not. But you can get a similar result using the method above - rendering yourself. Please note that html inline PHP is bad and you should do this in the view and starting new <?php ?>-tags for each php output etc ;)

Comment: ha! I was already doing that. I thought there would be a way to get the generated input so that it would be populated automatically etc. Thanks, it's the right answer even if it's not the one I wanted

Comment: If you just want to remove the dd-dt-dl tags you could remove these decorators/set your own decorators on the elements/forms ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the better solution is to extend the radio class to include a renderMultiOption($opt) function. In that function, duplicate the way the radio button renders in its stock render option (I believe you'll need to look at Zend_Form_Element_Multi as well, but not sure)

Really this should be something Zend includes, since one of the main reasons to viewscript is to arrange the rendered elements in a custom manner, not to hand-render the elements. I think it would be worth your while to extend the class in this case, as this would keep your viewscript more consistent. Probably you'd also want to make a method to render the singleton aspects of the radio button - label and open/close tag for the element itself.

I'm going to have to do this myself, so when I do I'll probably post how I did it. We need to custom-arrange radio buttons for a print form, but that shouldn't entail writing markup for the radio buttons individually.

Comment: I have come up with a solution, but I'm going to wait to publish it. It needs to be cleaned up a lot and I don't have time to do so. 

However, please note the following:

1. Zend_View_Helper_[x] is the conceptually correct way to implement this.
2. There currently doesn't seem to be a way to set a _partial_ view helper for a descendent of Zend_Form_Element_Multi to allow the rendering of individual elements (this doesn't make sense for some Multi elements.)

Comment: All in all, I've extended the class in our own library and written a method to output a radio button per-value by copying Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio's code. It's messy because there is a lot there I (nor you) have no need of. Mainly the need to pass the view so the functions work... _probably_ I don't need those functions but I don't have the time to fix the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Simple but Zend-like way to render own radio is to create own View Helper:

```
<?php

class Zend_View_Helper_Radio extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    protected $name;
    protected $value;
    protected $id;

    public function radio($name, $value, $id = null) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function render() {
        $html = '';

        $html .= '<input type=radio';
        if ($this->id) {
            $html .= ' id="' . htmlspecialchars($this->id) . '"';
        }
        $html .= ' name="' . htmlspecialchars($this->name) . '"';
        $html .= ' value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->value) . '"';
        $html .= ' />';

        return $html;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        try {
        return $this->render();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can render the elements as same as already mentioned by Hikaru-Shindo using the helper:

```
foreach ($form->gender->getMultiOptions() as $value => $name) {
    echo '<label for="gender-', $value, '">';
    echo $this->radio('gender', $value, 'gender-' . $value);
    echo '<img src="/css/gender-', $value, '.png">';
    echo $name, '</label>';
};
```

Of course you can create another View Helper specifically for your case and then render as

```
$this->genderSelection($form->gender->getMultiOptions());
```